# How to exit a form and return to previous form when an exception is caught at the 'InitializeComponent()';

Tags: c#, winforms

Method `model.FillDocumentList("RGArequest_Report", true);` returns a `NULL` value when the table is empty. I want this to check the table and if empty return to the previous form when the exception is caught.

```
public createScrapNote(IModel _Model)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.ControlBox = false;
    this.Bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
    this.TopMost = true;

    scrapNoteID = Convert.ToString(id.getscrapID());
    sn_tf.Text = scrapNoteID;

    try
    {
        model.FillDocumentList("RGArequest_Report", true);
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No Scrap Notes To Issue", "ERROR!!",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        //WANT TO RETURN TO PREVIOUS FORM HERE!!
    }
}
```

Comment: **Never ever catch a `NullReferenceException`! Fix the exception.**

Comment: Patrick is correct, you should handle it before it occurs not after.

Comment: You could throw a custom exception that is caught from the calling app to let it know that the constructor failed but listen to @PatrickHofman's advice...

Answer (score 0):

Don't have time to try this but it should work if you just use it where you need it. I suggest you make sure you don't get an exception however.

```
PreviousFormName prevForm = new PreviousFormName();
prevForm.show();
Close();
```